# VK-API, проблема с CORS

Tags: javascript, cors

Ни как не могу разобраться с CORS.

Есть вот такой простейший код:

```
function loadUserInfo(userId) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/users.get?version=5.57&user_ids=' + userId, false);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.send();
    if (xhr.status != 200) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).response.shift();
    }
}
```

С его помощью я хочу получить информацию о только что залогинившемся пользователе. Постоянно вылетает ошибка:

> vk.html:37 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/users.get?version=5.57&user_ids=209295007.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://mysite.ru' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

Я проверял базовые домены в приложении ВК, добавил `withCredentials = true`, но все это не решает проблему.

Comment: Нужно через протокол jsonp отправлять. `withCredentials = true` не поможет...... Либо использовать openAPI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По совету Алексея, релизовал всё с помощью протокола JSONP:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                var callbackResponse = (document.URL).split("#")[1];
                var responseParameters = (callbackResponse).split("&");
                var parameterMap = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < responseParameters.length; i++) {
                    parameterMap[responseParameters[i].split("=")[0]] = responseParameters[i].split("=")[1];
                }
                if (parameterMap.access_token !== undefined && parameterMap.access_token !== null) {
                    jsonp('https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/users.get?version=5.57&user_ids=' + parameterMap.user_id, function(userInfo) {
                        userInfo = userInfo.response[0];
                        console.log(userInfo);
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("Ошибка авторизации в ВК");
                }
                function jsonp(url, callback) {
                    var callbackName = 'jsonp_callback_' + Math.round(100000 * Math.random());
                    window[callbackName] = function(data) {
                        delete window[callbackName];
                        document.body.removeChild(script);
                        callback(data);
                    };

                    var script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.src = url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + 'callback=' + callbackName;
                    document.body.appendChild(script);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Redirecting...</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если кому актуально, то картинку на сервер с клиентского браузера с помощью js загрузить не получится.
Vk официально об этом заявили тут https://vk.com/faq11786